# Python - Merge data by time intervals (R data.table mimic?)

Tags: python, r, date, time-series, data.table

I'm just learning python and have a question about integrating data frames by time. For instance, say I have 2 separate data frames with irregular time intervals but grouped by study_id. I would like to join rows that come within 2 hours of each other.

Previously, I have used the data.table package in R for this. An example of this code is below.

```
df_new <- df1[df2, on="Study_ID", allow.cartesian=T][difftime(`date_df1`, `date_df2`, units="hours") <= 2 & difftime(`date_df1`, `date_df2`, units="hours") >= - 2]
```

This code then binds every instance where there are dates that are within 2 hours of each for each data frame. I am looking to see if there is any similar code for python? Ideally, I'd like to merge these rows so that I can find the max value that occurs between measurements that come either within 2 hours before or after the measurements.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Edit: Example of Dataframes

```
    ID   Date           HeartRate
    1    4/1/2019 04:13     56
    1    4/2/2019 05:30     45
    1    4/3/2019 22:10     61
    2    4/3/2019 23:13     62
    2    4/5/2019 15:10     67

    df2
    ID   Date             Weight
     1    4/1/2019 06:10     112
     1    4/2/2019 02:30     114
     1    4/3/2019 21:10     112.5
     2    4/3/2019 23:10     113
     2    4/4/2019 00:00     114

    Output (this is what I would love!)
    ID   Date(blood pressure)  HeartRate   Date(weight)   Weight
    1    4/1/2019 4:13            56       4/1/2019 06:10   112
    1    4/3/2019 22:10           61       4/3/2019 21:10   112.5
    2    4/3/2019 23:13           62       4/3/2019 23:10   113
    2    4/3/2019 23:13           62       4/4/2019 00:00   114
```

In this example, the second row in each dateframe is just removed since these measurements don' thave a pair within 2 hours. But the second to last row shown in df1 repeats because it has 2 cases in df2 that are within 2 hours.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the dataframe? I have difficulties imagining on what axis and dimensions we're talking here.

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock I have editted to add an example, thank you :)

Comment: @molecularrunner Are you still interested in a solution to this? I think I can help you but my solution doesn't include the last record, since there is a timelapse of 23 hours between them, unless the weight date is actually 4/4/2019.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save your dates as datetime, then you can do something similar to what you were doing in `data.table`, you perform a join between both dataframes and then filter the records which have a time difference less tan two hours.

```
# store as datetime
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

# join dataframes
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='ID', right_on='ID', 
                   suffixes=('(blood pressure)', '(weight)'))     
# calculate hour difference between the two dates
hour_dif = np.abs(merged['Date(blood pressure)'] - merged['Date(weight)'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
merged[hour_dif < 2]
```

Which yields

```
#    ID Date(blood pressure)  HeartRate        Date(weight)  Weight
# 0   1  2019-04-01 04:13:00         56 2019-04-01 06:10:00   112.0
# 8   1  2019-04-03 22:10:00         61 2019-04-03 21:10:00   112.5
# 9   2  2019-04-03 23:13:00         62 2019-04-03 23:10:00   113.0
```

Comment: thank you @josemz. I will give this a start. What i'm not sure this example will help with though, is the fact that there could be multiple weight measurements before heart rate or vice versa. So i don't neccessarily want to bind only the corresponding rows in each dataframe.

Comment: @molecularrunner feel free to edit the simple data in your question to adress those cases.

Comment: So cases as I explained, were reflected in the original data where I tried to show 4/3/2019 23:13 binding to 2 seperate weight measurements that were both within 2 hours.

Comment: So was the last record supposed to be 4/4/2019 00:00?

Comment: And I apologize, you had already pointed that out to me. And I did try your solution but then was getting errors with memory and I don't feel like my dataset is that large

Comment: Update! So the code is working now as I subset it, but it's just automatically creating duplicate rows? Which I think is the memory issue when I try and use the whole dataset? Any guesses as to why this is?